# Обновить первую совпадающую запись в таблице

Tags: python, sql, база-данных

У меня есть таблица. Нужно обновить первую запись на 2, у которой значение равно 1.
К примеру такая таблица

```
numbers
0
1
0
1
```

И должно стать так

```
numbers
0
2
0 
1
```

Comment: **первую** в каком порядке? Если у таблицы нет индексов, то она считается неупорядоченной и результат выполнения *select* или *update* будет непредсказуем в смысле порядка. Поэтому, совет такой: добавьте индекс, выберите (select) все записи с "1" в порядке индекса. Запомните индекс первой выбранной строки. А потом сделайте *update* строки с этим индексом.

Comment: select id, numbers from my_table where numbers=1 order by id desc limit 1;